# How to parallel a simple python for-loop assigning value to an array efficiently?

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, for-loop

I want to parallel a for-loop assigning value to an array in each iteration. For a simple example:

```
N = 100000
a = np.zeros(N)
for i in range(N):
    a[i] = i**2 + sum([j**(1/2) for j in range(10**4)])
```

I know this is not an efficient way to compute `a` but that is just for the example. The actual codes are more complicated but have a similar structure. And `sum([j**(1/2) for j in range(10**4)])` is just to cost some time for comparison with the non-parallel version.

It is easy in MALTAB using parfor and in Julia using Base.Threads. But it seems not to be easy in Python. Any clean, efficient way to do it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: That time filler sum line is confusing the problem.  As written it is nearly independent of the iterator and can evaluated once. But if it really represents something complicated that has to be evaluated once for each `i`, and can't be compiled or rewritten with numpy methods, there isn't much you can do - except use a multiprocessing package and accept its interprocess communication time penalties.

Comment: @hpulj That solves my question. The time filler sum does represent something complicated and can not be computed outside the loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no simple way, you'll have to use some of the complicated ways you've undoubtably already found while looking this up. CPython has a global interpreter lock, which will prevent you from leveraging parallelism at the Python interpreter level.

But your approach here is just not ideal.

For starters, you needlessly re-compute

```
sum([j**(1/2) for j in range(10**4)])
```

On every iteration. If you just do:

```
N = 100000
a = np.zeros(N)
x = sum([j**(1/2) for j in range(10**4)])
for i in range(N):
    a[i] = i**2 + x
```

Your code will be significantly faster (probably faster than what simply adding parallelism would do for you).

But more fundamentally, perhaps, you shouldn't be using `numpy` like this, it is going to be slow, it is designed for *vectorized operations*.

So what you *really want* is simply:

```
a = (np.arange(N)**2) + np.sqrt(np.arange(10**4)).sum()
```

So, just to emphasize how important choosing the right algorithm is, here is how much improvement you get by doing just that, in this case, no re-calculating something on every iteration which you only needed to do once:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: %%timeit
   ...: N = 10000
   ...: a = np.zeros(N)
   ...: for i in range(N):
   ...:     a[i] = i**2 + sum([j**(1/2) for j in range(10**4)])
   ...:
9.1 s ± 69.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [3]: %%timeit
   ...: N = 10000
   ...: a = np.zeros(N)
   ...: x = sum([j**(1/2) for j in range(10**4)])
   ...: for i in range(N):
   ...:     a[i] = i**2
   ...:
2.06 ms ± 25.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So severals orders of magnitude better just by doing that.

numpy vectorization can improve that even further:

```
In [5]: N = 10000

In [6]: %timeit (np.arange(N)**2) + np.sqrt(np.arange(10**4)).sum()
37.3 µs ± 763 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops ea
```

So before you try to throw parallelism at a problem, make sure your algorithm is ideal first, specially with low-hanging fruit like this. Then make sure you are using tools like numpy in a way that leverages their advantages.

Comment: The OP was using a for loop.  Did you consider putting the for loop in a function and decorating it with numba.jit(nopython=True)?  Probably still not ideal, but this is the type of thing the jit compilation excels at.

Comment: @tnknepp you could do that, but why when a vectorized solution is trivial?

Comment: I agree, but I just thought it would make for an interesting comparison.  I guess that's my stupid question for today.  ;)

Comment: @tnknepp I don't think it's a stupid question.